# Retain count of the start from 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, memory-leaks

In Following code

```
 NSURL *file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:soundName]];
     //        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:file];
     myExampleSound1 =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];
     myExampleSound1.volume=0.9;
     [myExampleSound1 prepareToPlay];
     myExampleSound1.delegate = self;
     [myExampleSound1 play];
     [soundsArray addObject:myExampleSound1];

     NSLog(@"RETAIN COUNT BEFORE RELEASE file = %d, myExampleSound1=%d, soundsArray=%d", [file retainCount],[myExampleSound1 retainCount], [soundsArray retainCount]);
     [file release];
     NSLog(@"RETAIN COUNT AFTER RELEASE file = %d, myExampleSound1=%d, soundsArray=%d", [file retainCount],[myExampleSound1 retainCount], [soundsArray retainCount]);
```

I am printin the retain count of file is 4 before release and 3 after release. Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. What's your question? 2. Don't use retainCount.

Comment: What guide did you read that said to use `retainCount`? I want to find the source so I can correct it if I can. It should never be used to determine object lifetimes. It shouldn't really be used at all.

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com